# How to find unmatched words from list with string

Tags: python

I have a string like

```
test_string = """
My name is 
My address
My location at 
"""
```

I have list of words that should present in above string

```
test_list = ("name","address","city")
```

I know i can use `all` function to ensure all the words in list present in string like:

```
if all(x in test_string for x in test_list):
    print("All matches")
else:
    # Here i want to find the missing items in the list (city)
```

How can I find the unmatched words in the list?

Comment: You were very close. `in` and `not in`: almost similar to your if, the else just look for negation :) `print({x for x in test_list if x not in test_string})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a negating check in an `if` condition in the expression for the else block:

```
test_string = """
My name is 
My address
My location at 
"""
test_list = ("name","address","city")
if all(x in test_string for x in test_list):
    print("All matches")
else:
   missing = set(x for x in test_list if x not in test_string)
   print(missing)

>> {'city'}
```

Second way using the `difference` method of `set`.

You test the equality of `test_list_set` and the `matched` set generated after applying the match condition. If they are equal `All matches` is printed

Else you find the difference of the two sets which gives you the missing elements:

```
test_string = """
My name is 
My address
My location at 
"""
test_list = ("name","address","city")
test_list_set = set(test_list)
matched = set(x for x in test_list if x in test_string )

if matched == test_list_set:
    print("All matches")
else:
    missing = test_list_set.difference(matched)
    print(missing)

>>  {'city'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it from sets

```
test_string = """
My name is 
My address
My location at 
"""
test_list = set(("name","address","city"))
not_included = test_list.difference(set(test_list.split(" "))
if not not_included:
   print("All matches")
else:
    print("Not included {}".format(not_included))
```

That will print you all words that not included in test_string

Answer (score 0):

You can find unmatched words this way

```
if len(set(test_string.split()) ^ set(test_list)) > 0:
    print("there is unmatched words")
else:
    print("All matched")
```